# Setting up a Jenkins Pipeline to Deploy a PHP Project from GitHub to Nginx on CentOS

Tags: php, nginx, jenkins, deployment, jenkins-pipeline

i cloned the php project from git repository in my centos machine, how to configure it to nginx. i dont understand what is the public directory of php project.

i installed php server in centos machine. I need to know the pipeline script in jenkins to deploy it in nginx